# Compare two arrays with php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I need some helps to compare some arrays with php, basically I have two arrays (mission and employee) :

Array mission :

```
Array(
[0] => Array (
    [days] => Monday
    [hours] => 1,0,0,0,0,0
)
[1] => Array
    (
        [days] => Tuesday
        [hours] => 1,1,0,0,0,1
    )
)
```

Array employee :

```
Array(
[0] => Array (
    [days] => Monday
    [hours] => 1,0,0,0,0,0
)
[1] => Array
    (
        [days] => Tuesday
        [hours] => 1,1,0,0,0,1
    )
)
[1] => Array
    (
        [days] => Wednesday
        [hours] => 1,1,0,0,0,1
    )
)
```

The aim is to compare if employee is available for a mission, it means if employee is available (above case) Monday **and** Tuesday with included hours to work (1 and 0 represents hours and position of each item is very important).

Firstly employee is not available if number of mission days is superior to employee day :

```
foreach ($mission as $m) {
    # code...
    $m_days[] = $m['days'];
    foreach ($employee as $e) {
        $e_days[] = $e['days'];
    }
    $i++;
}
/// First condition if m_days > e_days so valid
$valid = (sizeof($m_days) > sizeof($e_days)) ? true : false;
```

After that I have no idea to compare if employee is at least available for mission hours, for example if mission is a Monday with hours : 1,1,0,0,0,1 and employee is free for Monday with hours : 1,1,1,0,0,1 he can take the mission, but if he is available Monday with hours : 1,0,0,0,0,1 he cannot take the mission.

With array_diff it is not working as demonstrated [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3bd017dc429a431ab84b5b701fcd7d8dc3a947d8)

Could you help me please ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try using **array_diff**

Example array_diff()

```
<?php
$array1 = array("a" => "car", "bike", "skateboard", "bike");
$array2 = array("b" => "car", "boat", "bike");
$result = array_diff($array1, $array2);

print_r($result);
?>
```

Multiple occurrences in $array1 are all treated the same way. This will output :

```
Array
(
    [1] => skateboard
)
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your response but I think area_diff will do the job, based on your script my arrays output : 
Please see : http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3bd017dc429a431ab84b5b701fcd7d8dc3a947d8
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Array to string conversion in <b>[...][...]</b> on line <b>5</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Array to string conversion in <b>[...][...]</b> on line <b>5</b><br />
Array
(
)